# Implement Factory pattern using Generics once and for all

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

Consider this. I want to create a factory (the pattern, not planing a new genesis) that creates animals. I thought I would be smart and create a class that has the 3 things I will need for this to work,

- A delegate that returns an abstract animal
- A creation method that returns a specific animal for every animal
- An instance of each creation method using the delegate

Tired of doing this again and gain every time I need to use the factory pattern, I thought I would be extra smart and solve it once for all. So, I created this nifty class

```
class Factorable<T> where T: class, new() 
{
    delegate T CreateDelegate();
    static CreateDelegate DoCreate = new CreateDelegate (CreateSelf);
    static T CreateSelf()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

class Factory<T> where T : Factorable<T>
{
    public Factorable<T>.CreateDelegate CreationMethod ;
}
```

I thought, cool, I can make the top class (Animal) inherit from this class so I don't have to write and instantiate all the specific creation methods for all the animals. It will all be done thanks to the generics. Almost... see this:

```
class Animal:Factorable<Animal> {...}
class Bird:Animal {...}

Factory genesis = new Factory<Animal>();
genesis.CreationMethod = Animal.DoCreate;
Animal instance = genesis.CreateAnimal();  //instance is a brand new abstract Animal

genesis.CreationMethod = Bird.DoCreate;  //lets make it create birds!
instance = genesis.CreateAnimal();  // wrong, instance is still an abstract Animal
```

Is there any way to fix this? I would like the CreateSelf method that Bird has inherited to create Birds, not abstract Animals (without having to write a new method for Bird). Is there a way to specify that Animal inherits from Factorable but have its descendants to override the generic T with its own type?

Something (this is silly code, does not work) like this

```
class Animal:Factorable<Animal... or better the actual type of the class that has inherited>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how can an `Animal` inherit from a Generic of itself `Factorable<Animal>`?

Comment: @MikeC That's possible in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aren't you overcomplicating a bit? Assuming `Animal` is your base class:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : Animal, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = Factory.Create<Animal>();
var b = Factory.Create<Bird>();
```

**UPDATE**

After reading your comment this is how I understand it: object calling the factory does not know the exact type of the created instance. It only knows that it's either Animal or Animal-derived class. So, how about this:

```
public class Factory
{
    private Type _outputType = typeof(Animal);

    public void Produces<T>() where T : Animal, new()
    {
        _outputType = typeof(T);
    }

    public Animal CreateAnimal()
    {
        return (Animal)Activator.CreateInstance(_outputType);
    }
}
```

Note: Making the output type private and using the `Produces<T>` to set it provides easy way to ensure that output type is Animal or derived.

Usage:

```
var f = new Factory();  // factory produces animals
var a = f.CreateAnimal();
f.Produces<Bird>();     // from now on factory produces birds
var b = f.CreateAnimal();
```

Comment: A factory creates high level objects allowing other classes that need it to create the abstract type. It should allow you, though, to inject a descendant class type into an already finished hierarchy. That is the reason for my delegate. Suppose I have a library to deal with a zoo with Cage classes. The Cage uses the Factory to create Animals. The AnimalHandler class too. The whole library is finished and sealed in a DLL. Now I want to create an Aviary application. Ideally, there would be a way to tell the Factory: OK, don't create Animals, please create only Birds (my delegate).

Comment: Updated my answer. Please note that variable `b` is still of type `Animal` but holds an instance of the `Bird` class. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Cool! That is exactly what I was looking for. Green check mark for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a static method. Try this:

```
class Factorable<T> where T: class, new() 
{
    delegate T CreateDelegate();
    CreateDelegate DoCreate = new CreateDelegate (CreateSelf);
    T CreateSelf()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
class Animal : Factorable<Animal>...
...
Factory genesis = new Factory();
genesis.CreateAnimal = (new Animal()).DoCreate;
Animal instance = genesis.CreateAnimal(); 

genesis.CreateAnimal = (new Bird()).DoCreate;
instance = genesis.CreateAnimal();
```